# qt audio output example not building -- missing generator class declaration

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors

Never had any problem building any of the qt examples until i tried the audio examples.

Several of them do not build.

I am assuming I am missing some dependency, setting, or something like that.

When I try to build, for example, the audio output example, I get:

> C:\Qt\Examples\Qt-5.3\multimedia\audiooutput\audiooutput.cpp:62: error: 'Generator' does not name a type
>    Generator::Generator

And looking in the header, I do not see that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in version 5.3.    The bug was resolved in 5.4.   If anyone else runs into this, upgrade to 5.4 or newer and they will build correctly.